# How to create a counter in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script src="../plugin/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugin/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugin/jquery.form.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/form.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var id = "input" + $(this).attr("id").replace("field","");
        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\" class=\"fieldname\" />");
        var fType = $("<select class=\"fieldtype\"><option value=\"checkbox\">Checked</option><option value=\"textbox\">Text</option><option value=\"textarea\">Paragraph</option></select>");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fName);
        fieldWrapper.append(fType);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });
});

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<form id="edit" method="post" action="config.php" >
<fieldset id="buildyourform">
    <legend>Build your own form!</legend>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
<input type="submit">
<div class="spacer"></div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code of a  dynamic form , however, currently the text box name and select box name is 'inputadd', i would like to change it to input1, input2, input3, that means when user add a field , it will be counter+1 and the name of text field , select field will be that string, and the same if remove counter -1 , How can i modify the code to achieve this?Thank you

Comment: I recommend to use single quote (') instead of double quotes (") for strings in JavaScript. Your code will be waaaay more readable.

Comment: Then your strings can look something like `'<input type="text" id="' + id + '" name="' + id + '" class="fieldname" />'` because you do not need to escape double quotes `"` when they are inside single quotes `'`

Comment: Mind you, it works in reverse, too.  You don't need to escape single quotes from inside double quotes either.  Also, could someone explain clearly why this question is sitting at -3?  In general, if you're going to downvote someone, it seems worthwhile to make sure they know *why*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `input[]` instead of `input1`, `input2`, `input3`, ...

```
<form id="your-form">
    <li><input type="text" name="input[]" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="input[]" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="input[]" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="input[]" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="input[]" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="input[]" /></li>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This should give you the POST field data as an array of all the `input[]` elements, for example in PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST['input'] as $input) {
    echo $input . PHP_EOL;
}
```

that way you won't have to keep count in JavaScript, you'll only have to add another field with `name="input[]"`.

Comment: Thankyou , how can  i add a string eg. Please input name , before each input box?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways - with a global variable:

```
int formcount = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var id = formcount++;
    });
});
```

Or counting how many elements with 'fieldwrapper' class there is in '#buildyourform' (preferable):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var id = $('#buildyourform .fieldwrapper').size();
    });
});
```

(Just remember that id can't start with a number, you should prefix it with a alphabetic character)

Comment: You probably meant `.length` instead of `.count()`

Comment: _"The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call."_

Comment: @gdoron - I usually prefer size over length because it's more consistent with jQuery API, so it's more readable IMHO. This "overhead" is usually not a problem... Thanks for the info, OP can just go with whichever he wants ;)

Comment: Thankyou , how can  i add a string eg. Please input name , before each input box?